# Sending Mail using JAVA and JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, email, jakarta-mail

here i wanted to send mail using Java and JSP .

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sending Mail Through JSP</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body bgcolor="khaki">
    <form action="mailJSP.jsp">
        <table>
            <tr><td><b><font color="red">To:
                </td>
                <td><b><b><input type="text" name="mail" value="Enter sender mail-id"/><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b><font color="red">Subject:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="sub" value="Enter Subject Line"><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b><font color="red">Message Text:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea rows="12" cols="80" name="mess"></textarea><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body></html>
```

**mailJSP.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*,javax.mail.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*" %>
<%
//Creating a result for getting status that messsage is delivered or not!
String result;
// Get recipient's email-ID, message & subject-line from index.html page
final String to = request.getParameter("mail");
final String subject = request.getParameter("sub");
final String messg = request.getParameter("mess");

// Sender's email ID and password needs to be mentioned
final String from = "my mail";
final String pass = "my pass";

// Defining the gmail host
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

// Creating Properties object
Properties props = new Properties();

// Defining properties
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.user", from);
props.put("mail.password", pass);
props.put("mail.port", "465");

// Authorized the Session object.
Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(from, pass);
    }
});

try {
    // Create a default MimeMessage object.
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    // Set From: header field of the header.
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    // Set To: header field of the header.
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            new InternetAddress(to));
    // Set Subject: header field
    message.setSubject(subject);
    // Now set the actual message
    message.setText(messg);
    // Send message
    Transport.send(message);
    result = "Your mail sent successfully....";
} catch (MessagingException mex) {
    mex.printStackTrace();
    result = "Error: unable to send mail....";
}
%>`enter code here`
 <title>Sending Mail in JSP</title>
 <h1><center><font color="blue">Sending Mail Using JSP</font></h1>
 <b><center><font color="red">
 <% out.println(result);%></b>
```

I also want to add that i use Netbeans IDE and Apache Server and i've added all the jar files needed for it, but still i'm getting Exception and ends with "Unable to send". So i'm confused where i made the mistake ?

Stacktrace:

```
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:476)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**Exception**

```
exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 74 in the jsp file: /mailJSP.jsp
The local variable result may not have been initialized
71: %>
72: <title>Sending Mail in JSP</title>
73: <h1><center><font color="blue">Sending Mail Using JSP</font></h1>
74: <b><center><font color="red"><% out.println(result);%></b>
```

Hope it adds more info !

Comment: content of mex.printStackTrace(); ?

Comment: I put it for printing the caught Exception ! But once i run the code nothing is caught in netbeans output console :(

Comment: Do the versions of jar files matter ?

Comment: @bish : i've added the respective exceptions !

Comment: I can see the stacl trace, not the exception...

Comment: @CedricSimon: i've added the Exceptions raised !

Answer (score 1):

```
An error occurred at line: 74 in the jsp file: /mailJSP.jsp
```

The local variable result may not have been initialized

```
String result = new String();
```

initialize the variable

For the second exception

```
private final String SSL_FACTORY  =  "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
int port = 465;
if ("smtp.gmail.com".equals(host)) {
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",SSL_FACTORY);
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback","false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port",String.valueOf(port));
  }
```

Comment: Now new Exception pops out :
Could not connect to SMTP Host :smtp.gmail.com, port : 25, So how can i resolve this?

Comment: [Get rid of all that socket factory stuff](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) above and follow [these instructions for connecting to Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).

Comment: @SJith In regards to the exception you have posted in the comments on this answer have you set your gmail account to permit outside applications to send mail through your account, I had a similar problem. If you have not check the email account and see if you have received an email from google stating that they blocked an attempted sign in to your account and follow the instructions there, I have some simple to follow steps if you would like me to post them but I want to be sure that you have checked that your account is set up properly first or you will receive another exception

Comment: @RichardDavy: Yes sir,I've enabled the limit in my account settings, but still i'm not able to send though !

Comment: the Exception raised is "Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25" and i have no idea regarding this !

Comment: Okay cool I, will post what I have for you in the next couple of hours, I had problems with email also, just let me get around a computer and I will help you out my friend

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm) might help you. Worked for me! Also, you should have showed the Stack Trace. It helps to get a better understanding if something unusually has gone wrong with your program.

Comment: But Shubham, something should be wrong here , but i am unable to find out the pit here !

Answer (score 0):

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

you enabled tls but in fact you use ssl (port 465).
Try this:

```
Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(System.getProperties());
        Transport transport = new SMTPTransport(mailSession, new URLName("smtp.gmail.com"));
        transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtps");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, "email@email.com", "Your-Password-Here");
        MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        m.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@email.addr"));
        Address[] toAddr = new InternetAddress[]{ new InternetAddress("to@email@email.addr") };
        m.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddr);
        m.setSubject("set subject if you wish");
        m.setSentDate(new java.util.Date());
        String text = "BODY OF EMAIL";
        m.setContent(text, "text/plain");
        transport.sendMessage(m, m.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           out.println(e.getMessage() + " - " + e.toString());
           e.printStackTrace();

       }
```